# Lokijs - Simple query not working

Tags: node.js, lokijs

I'm querying something simple from the database and it keeps returning me an empty array. I tried several ways following the documentation on the site.

```
user.chain().find({ email: 'test@gmail.com' }).data();
```

I tried this as well:

```
user.find({ email: 'test@gmail.com' });
```

I also added this before of course:

```
var user = db.addCollection('User', {
 indices: ['email']
});
```

I also tried it with the `Dynamic View` but it's not working neither.

Any Ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know that you have to load the database before querying. Here is a simple example:

```
db.loadDatabase({}, function () {
 var user = db.getCollection('User');
 console.log(user.findOne({ 'email': 'example@gmail.com' }));
});
```

Hope it helps someone!